# How to provide weighted eval set to XGBClassifier.fit()?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

From the [sklearn-style API of XGBClassifier](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit), we can provide eval examples for early-stopping.

> **eval_set** (list, optional) – A list of (X, y) pairs to use as a
>   validation set for early-stopping

However, the format only mentions a pair of features and labels. So if the doc is accurate, there is no place to provide weights for these eval examples.

Am I missing anything?

If it's not achievable in the sklearn-style, is it supported in the original (i.e. non-sklearn) XGBClassifier API? A short example will be nice, since I never used that version of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - UPDATED per conversation in comments

Given that you have a target-variable representing real-valued gain/loss values which you would like to classify as "gain" or "loss", and you would like to make sure the validation-set of the classifier weighs the large-absolute-value gains/losses heaviest, here are two possible approaches:

1. Create a custom classifier which is just XGBoostRegressor fed to a treshold where the real-valued regression predictions are converted to 1/0 or "gain"/"loss" classifications. The .fit() method of this classifier would just call .fit() of xgbregressor, while .predict() method of this classifier would call .predict() of the regressor and then return the thresholded category predictions.
2. you mentioned you would like to try weighting the treatment of the records in your validation set, but there is no option for this in xgboost. The way to implement this would be to implement a custom `eval-metric`. However, you pointed out that `eval_metric` must be able to return a score for a single label/pred record at a time, so it couldn't accept all your row-values and perform the weighting in the eval metric. The solution to this you mentioned in your comment was "create a callable which has a ref to all validation examples, pass the indices (instead of labels and scores) into eval_set, use the indices to fetch labels and scores from within the callable and return metric for each validation examples." This should also work.

I would tend to prefer option 1 as more straightforward, but trying two different approaches and comparing results is generally a good idea if you have the time, so interested how these turn out for you.

Comment: Yes I know about `sample_weight` and agree that it looks irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Per `eval_metric`, apparently the callable only takes one label-score pair at a time so it's not designed to pass in weights for each of the validation examples. I suppose one can create a callable which has a ref to all validation examples, pass the indices (instead of labels and scores) into `eval_set`, use the indices to fetch labels and scores from within the callable and return metric for each validation examples. One can normalize the total weight to be 1. This way value returned for each validation example will sum up to the overall weighted metric.

Comment: I think your suggestion is doable. I will wait for a few days to see if there is better suggestion. If none, I will mark yours as the answer. Thank you for the effort! For the sake of other readers, do you want to furnish your answer w/ the approach I wrote above w/ your own words, or refer to my comment?

Comment: sure I can add a reference/quote to your comment. But first I want to ask...the approach you describe sounds doable but perhaps overly complicated. Can you elaborate a bit on where your weightings come from, or what they represent? Could you really not get away with using a rule such as e.g. 'misclassifying red marbles is twice as expensive as misclassifying white ones'? If that really doesn't work for you though, I agree that passing an extra param to `eval_metric` for index of your record, which maps to a sample-weight (calculated elsewhere), makes sense.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is basically I get a list of items, which has a real-valued gain/loss. I want to do a classification (i.e. whether an item will lead to gain or loss) but I want to make sure the items associated w/ high gain/loss magnitudes are respected more than the mediocre. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think my suggestion then is the following: Use XGBRegressor not XGBClassifier, and predict the real-valued gain/loss (not just classify it as +/- 0). Then the output of that real-valued prediction gets passed to a threshold classifier, where presumably your threshold would be 0 for classifying a prediction as "gain" or "loss". Then everything that goes into your training/validation/scoring is indeed affected proportionally more by the higher-absolute-value gains/losses. But I think this is a much more straightforward approach than what we discussed before. Does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: Yeah I see regression as a reasonable alternative formulation of the problem. So, thank you for sharing your thoughts which confirms my intuition. But to be honest I find weighted classification as equally reasonable as regression. In fact I will want to try both and see which one ends up better. In theory, regression optimizes for predicting the actual gain/loss while weighted classification optimizes for picking the correct side (w/ the magnitude of the consequence in mind). I don't see clear reason for one to be better than the other in terms of business metrics (e.g. sum of triggered g/l).

Answer (score 4):

As of a few weeks ago, there is a new parameter for the `fit` method, `sample_weight_eval_set`, that allows you to do exactly this. It takes a list of weight variables, i.e. one per evaluation set. I don't think this feature has made it into a stable release yet, but it is available right now if you compile xgboost from source.

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/b018ef104f0c24efaedfbc896986ad3ed1b66774/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L235